# box-shadow Affecting Font Weight

Tags: css

I have a fixed navbar that I am giving a drop shadow effect. That works fine, however it seems to also be affecting all the text inside and makes the font weight appear slimmer.

How can I make it stop changing the font?

http://jsfiddle.net/dvY4A/1/

**HTML**

```
<nav id="nav1" class="dropshadow">Hello World</nav>
<button>toggle drop shadow</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav1 {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  font-size:20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height:20px;
  background:white;
}
button {
    margin-top:50px;
}
.dropshadow {  
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference in font weight in any browser.

Comment: @BoltClock Hmm, when I toggle I am seeing the issue in Safari on OS X. In my actual code I am seeing the problem in Chrome as well.

Comment: The difference only seems to appear on Safari on OSX (hence why I deleted my answer). I think it could be a Safari bug.

Comment: As a workaround, I've placed an equal sized `div` underneath and put the drop shadow around that. http://jsfiddle.net/dvY4A/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer and it involves some issues at the operating system level.

I've updated the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/dvY4A/5/

All it took was adding the property `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` to the `#nav1` block.

More details about it can be found here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Oct/0014.html

But basically, there are two rendering modes for text, grayscale and subpixel-antialiased.  For technical reasons, the browser tries to switch between the two during certain operations like hardware acceleration, which the box-shadow must be using.

I'm still using my workaround just in case but I may set this property at some point.